# Why can't the circle arc be greater than pi using gmsh?

Tags: c++

I'm using [gmsh](http://gmsh.info/) to create a mesh for some 2D geometry that was created on Solidworks, saved as sheet metal DXF, then converted to Gmsh's ".geo" file format [using this code](https://github.com/cycheung/gmsh/blob/master/utils/converters/autocad/dxf2geo.cpp).

When I read the documentation for gmsh, it specifically says in more than one place that the circle arcs cannot be greater than pi. I really have two questions:

1. Why can't one have a circle arc greater than pi?
2. What exactly is meant by circle arc greather than pi? The arc length, radius or other?

This is out of pure curiosity. I am a newbie at meshing and CFD. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an arc defined by two points and the radius, there are two solutions (think of a secant breaking into two parts a circumference).

If the angle covered by the arc is given, you still have two solutions, depending on going from point 1 to point 2 or the opposite way. Think of having two circumferences that satisfy the condition.

An easy way to avoid those issues is limiting the angle p1-center-p2 to pi.

An arc with total angle greater than pi can be expresed by two smaller arcs.

Comment: That makes sense, I had a few arcs with an angle of exactly pi and it didn't like that very much.  I will split them into two arcs of pi/2. Thanks!